# Объединение QImage без использования QGraphicScene

Tags: qt, qimage

Есть ли варианты объединения нескольких изображений без использования qgraphicscene? Если да, то какие? И что использовать предпочтительнее, если конечная цель получение объединенного изображения и сохранение его в файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`QPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) и [`QPainter::drawImage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage-4), для рисования на объекте `QPixmap`. Это возможно благодаря тому, что `QPixmap` наследует `QPaintDevice`, который как раз используется для рисования в `QPainter`.

Как только `QPixmap` будет отрисован, сохранение его в файл не составит труда.